# Cumulative Sum Group By Month

Tags: sql, hadoop, cloudera, impala

I need to do cumulative sum on one of the field(value column from above data) along with grouping it by month. Here is how my data looks:

[image]

I need the output as follows:

[image]

I am doing this in Impala, I tried couple of things, but it did not worked.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In a comment to one Answer you change the scope of the question from just the summation to also needing the average. 1) please don't edit the scope of a question after answers have been given, instead open a new question. 2) please don't hide details to a question in comments, please edit the question to ensure all details are there. 3) please confirm what average you want; unweighted mean, weighted mean, mode, median, etc (do this by editing your question to add what results you expect for the cumulative average column, for the sample data you've given; using formatted text, not images).

Answer (score 3):

Since analytic functions are applied to the select list expressions after the aggregation, you may wrap aggregation `sum` with an analytic `sum` ordered by month:

> ```
> with t(id, dt, val) as (
>   select *
>   from(values
>     (1, date '2022-01-10', 9),
>     (2, date '2022-01-15', 8),
>     (3, date '2022-02-14', 9),
>     (4, date '2022-02-18', 12),
>     (5, date '2022-02-23', 15)
>   ) a
> )
> select
>   date_trunc('month', dt) as mon
>   , sum(sum(val)) over(
>     order by date_trunc('month', dt) asc
>   ) as rsum
>   , sum(val) as mon_val
>   , round(avg(sum(val)) over(
>     order by date_trunc('month', dt) asc
>   ), 3) as r_avg
> from t
> group by 1
> ```
>
> mon                    | rsum | mon_val |  r_avg
> :--------------------- | ---: | ------: | -----:
> 2022-01-01 00:00:00+00 |   17 |      17 | 17.000
> 2022-02-01 00:00:00+00 |   53 |      36 | 26.500

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=44cd1c85387abee6db93ac0256fd199c)*

The same in Impala:

[image]

| mon | rsum | vers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 17 | impalad version 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT RELEASE (build 27b919fc8a5907648349aa48eefc894e15a5a6d4) Built on Tue Aug 3 21:19:39 UTC 2021 |
| 2022-02-01 | 53 | impalad version 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT RELEASE (build 27b919fc8a5907648349aa48eefc894e15a5a6d4) Built on Tue Aug 3 21:19:39 UTC 2021 |

Comment: @nbk basically this should work in most of the modern databases with slightly different syntax for date truncation. But fortunately it's the same in Impala

Comment: @nbk Well, I had to get off my bed and turn on a laptop to provide a screenshot that exactly the same code works fine) Please, check an updated answer

Comment: @astentx this works for sum. I am wondering is there any way to get the average YTD cum? So for example for month of january it should look for jan1-jan31 and get the average. for month of feb, it should look for jan1-feb28 and get the average?

Comment: @user12487929 The same for the `avg`: aggregate functions are calculated first, then analytic function is applied to the aggregated result (as it would be in case of subquery with aggregation). I've updated my answer with `avg`

Comment: Note: This is an average of averages, a weighted average. It gives `FebCumAvg=[ (9+8)/2 + (9+12+15)/3 ] / 2`, the unweighted average would just be `(9+8+9+12+15)/5` the code for which would be `SUM(SUM(value)) OVER <window> / SUM(COUNT(value)) OVER <window>`. Without asking the OP to clarify what they mean by average, this answer should state its assumptions or provide the available options (not just one, without mentioning other exist).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
SELECT MONTH, SUM(value) FROM yourtable GROUP BY MONTH(month)
```

Comment: Doesn't do the cumulative sum, and the select clause doesn't match the group by clause.